# Calculate kinematic data within a PostGIS trajectory

Tags: postgis, trajectory, trajectories

I have a number of glider flight tracks recorded in GPX format and I would like to extract kinematic data such as instantaneous vertical velocity for charting and further analysis.

There's plenty of literature that suggests using PostGIS trajectories (Linestring ZM geometry type) is generally the way to go (e.g. https://anitagraser.com/2018/04/16/movement-data-in-gis-12-why-you-should-be-using-postgis-trajectories/). But it's not clear to me if additional 'auxiliary' columns can be added to a LinestringZM geometry to hold kinematic data, or if it need to have data data as PointZM and then add field for the additional data I want to calculate.

Any thoughts / advice as I begin this journey (pun intended)?

Comment: There's a multitude of possible approaches here and which to choose depends on your use cases further down the road. You cannot add more info to the actual (geometric) *types* than there are ordinates, with the *M* ordinate being the auxiliary storage for e.g. linear referencing (but can be anything, really). Obviously you can add columns to your relations, but a *LineString* is a single entity consisting of vertices, effectively de-normalizing *Point* entities into a single container - so any column values on post-aggregated *Points* will have to follow de-normalization accordingly.

Comment: However, you can always collect *PointZM* entities into *LineStringZM* entities on-the-fly if needed, as they should strictly be in sequence; this allows you to run calculations on e.g. consecutive *Z* values of the *Point* sequences, or any other metric that needs to consider measurements along a given trajectory sequentially. On the other hand, you can create multi-valued columns - arrays or key/value storage types, or even custom types - along with the aggregated *LineStringZM* entities, that hold the results in a sequentially referenced manner (i.e. array indices <-> order of vertices).

Comment: GIS SE uses a Focused question/Best answer model. Queries for "thoughts and advice" are off topic here. In theory, this would be suitable in [Chat], but Chat doesn't see the volume of participation of the Q&A site.